# Multiple objects in @RequestBody possible?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is it possible to pass multiple objects to the @RequestBody from Spring Boot like this?

```
public void storeSecretKey(@RequestBody final KeyStoreRequest keyStoreRequest, @RequestBody final SecretKeyDTO secretKeyDTO) throws CertificateException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchProviderException {
```

or do i have to write like a wrapper class that combines both of the objects that i need data from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@RequestBody` will be used to read the body of the http request which is just 1.

Then inside the body of the http request there can be several objects contained, but all should belong to the same body of http request.

If we talk about `json` then the http body request would be in the form

```
{
   object1: { },
   object2: { },
   ...
}
```

So you can have only 1 `@RequestBody` which could then contain several nested objects like `object1`, `object2`, ...etc

In your case it would be

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class WrapperRequestExample {  
     private KeyStoreRequest keyStoreRequest;
     private SecretKeyDTO secretKeyDTO;
}
```

and your controller will then be

```
 public void storeSecretKey(@RequestBody WrapperRequestExample wrapperRequestExample) {
        wrapperRequestExample.getKeyStoreRequest(); //access keyStoreRequest
        wrapperRequestExample.getSecretKeyDTO(); //access secretKeyDTO
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what i thought of with creating the wrapper class.

Comment: @Sinnedkid sure you can then read nested properties like `wrapperRequestExample.getKeyStoreRequest().getKeyStoreName()`. However you need to use the @RequestBody in some wrapper class that contains what you expect to receive in the http request body if you expect several different objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple body parameters to your path operation function, even though a request can only have a single body.

Comment: thanks for your answer. What would happen to additional body parameters? Would they be null then?